# JQuery Issue with all browsers but IE 6.0/7.0 :)

Tags: jquery, ajax

Never thought I'd have this problem :)

The following snippet of code works in IE 6.0/7.0 but none of the other browsers (well, IE 8.0 in "compatibility view"):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Search button code
    $('#btnSearch').click(function() { //start function when button is clicked
            var sid = $('#search_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                    method: "get",url: "controller.php",data: { search_id:sid, action:'search'} ,
                    beforeSend: function(){$("#loading").show("slow");}, //show loading just when link is clicked
                    complete: function(){ $("#loading").hide("slow");}, //stop showing loading when the process is complete
                    success: function(html){ //so, if data is retrieved, store it in html
                            $('.main_content').html(html); //show the html inside .main_content div
                            $('.main_content').show("slow"); //animation
                    }
            });

            $("form").each(function() {
                    this.reset();
            });
    });
});
```

HTML looks like (only relevant parts included):

```
<div>
<form id="srchForm" method="post" action="">
<p><abbr title="Search ID"><label for="search_id">Search ID:</label></abbr><input   type="text" name="search_id" id="search_id">
<button id="btnSearch" value="search">go</button>
</p>
</form>
<div id="loading">LOADING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!<br></div>
<hr>
<div id="main_content" class="main_content"></div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="add_content"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What's happening?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Firefox JavaScript console?

Comment: No errors in Firefox JavaScript console.

Comment: It is not executing the callbacks.  Specifically, the "loading div" is not showing/hiding and the "main_content div" is not getting loaded with the returned html. Except in IE 6/7 where is works as I expected.

Comment: Have you verified that it isn't a cross-browser html issue? Also, if you console.log the beforeSend and complete events are you getting anything in FF?

Comment: Changing the tag from "button" to "input" fixed it.  But was I was receiving in FF/FB console.log was verification of everything working but the actual complete event.

Comment: err, "But what I was receiving"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a wild guess, could you try to define your button as 'input' tag instead of 'button' tag?

```
<input id="btnSearch" value="search" type="button" /> //Use this
<button id="btnSearch" value="search">go</button> //instead of this
```

Try it and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Not bad for a wild guess.  That appears to have fixed it.

Not sure I can thank you properly but THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: That's great. In your code listing, that was the only code which seemed out of place and hence my guess.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look it looks like:

The data property of the ajax method allows both JavaScript Objects and Strings, but I have never had any luck using anything other than a JSON String. In IE you can use JSON.Stringify() but you should take a look at some of the JQuery Plugins. For example this one [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/):

```
data: { search_id:sid, action:'search'} ,
```

would become:

```
data: $.toJSON({ search_id:sid, action:'search'}) ,
```

Secondly:

```
$('.main_content').html(thml);
```

It looks like you wrote 'thml' instead of 'html'.

Otherwise the code looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you.

I'll try the First suggestion.  On the second, it was a quick typo.  The actual variable name had too much information in it :)

Comment: This is incorrect. jQuery will happily take a javascript object into the data property and serialize it accordingly. http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: It does allow objects but I have never been able to get it to work without converting it to a JSON String first, so I was just stating what I thought might help get it working.